# Dropdown TextArea in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a project in WPF that has a ListView.
I'd like to add a combobox-like control to one of the columns, but instead of a list of items, I want it to show some text that will be in a property of the object bound to the ListViewItem.
Something like the stacktrace field in the Exception Details Window in Visual Studio.

[image: Exception View]

I've been searching for this but I could only find a control that was part of a paid control pack.
Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe that is just a multi-line textbox... Have you looked into its options?

Comment: It sounds to me like it might be more like a single-line `textbox` that shows the users the first line of text with a dropdown that shows a multi-line textbox where they can scroll through all of the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be a simple **UserControl** with three elements - a TextBox, a Popup and a Togglebutton. The textbox should be placed inside and outside of the Popup. The one inside the Popup should have **TextWrap** enabled and outside is not. The **IsOpen** property of **Popup** should bound to IsChecked of **ToggleButton**. The XAML of UserControl look like below,

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication6.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         MinWidth="150"
         x:Name="root"
         VerticalAlignment="Center">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox  Text="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=Text}"/>
    <ToggleButton Grid.Column="1" Width="20"
                  x:Name="toggle">
        <Path x:Name="Arrow"
              Grid.Column="1"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"
              Fill="Black" />
    </ToggleButton>
    <Popup IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=toggle, Path=IsChecked}" StaysOpen="False"
           Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=Text}"
                 Width="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=ActualWidth}"
                 IsReadOnly="True"
                 AcceptsReturn="True"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

Remeber you need a DependecyProperty named ***Text*** in your userControl.

Comment: It works, I just have to change the style a little bit cause it got a little messed up in the app. Thank you!